# Offline productivity

Tags: windows, firefox, sync, gmail

On some days I'm commuting 2hrs (oneway) in the train. I don't have any mobile internet nor is there always WiFi service in the train. Because of security reasons I can't do any work in the train so I'm trying to work on my geek time. I'm looking for general solutions on how to do this (I'm on FireFox/Windows but I don't think it matters)

- Email works perfectly with GMail offline. It syncs directly when online and remembers complicated stuff.
- So far I used the ScrapBook plugin to store an website. It works good, but I have to download my favorite news page every day again - I want it to sync as soon as possible. It would even be more awesome if I could click a page on my desktop and my laptop would sync as soon as it has the chance. (edit: maybe the autosave plugin for scrapbook can do this)
- Similarly, I use the Downloadhelper plugin to download YouTube vids, but I'd like something that automatically downloads videos from a given channel.

Any tips are welcome. So far my early morning schedule is: wake up, power on laptop, make coffee, power off laptop and leave within 10 minutes (enough time for GMail to sync) but I can imagine a system where my laptop stays on during the night (or boots before I wake (and makes me coffee :])).

Comment: you could define `read a book` as `productivity` the same way you can define it as `read mail and surf websites`, even more. so, read a book.

Comment: ` It works good, but I have to download my favorite news page every day again ` --> a decent RSS reader should cache the articles

Comment: You'd probably find [the Read It Later extension](http://readitlaterlist.com) for Firefox helpful, since it has a function to save things for offline. It doesn't quite solve any of your listed needs, though.

Comment: Combination of read it later with joliprint (http://joliprint.com/) looks interesting; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe combination of http://www.instapaper.com and a kindle (or kindle for pc) will help you.

You can look it's [extras](http://www.instapaper.com/extras)...